# UNION con SQL, mostrar valores en orden antes de unirlos

Tags: sql

Tengo el siguiente problema, hago una consulta donde quiero unir tres en una con UNION, todo bien para unirlas, pero como la consultas se trata de encontrar los 3 valores mas altos en 3 clasificaciones diferentes A y AA, AAA; cuando uso ORDER BY, en cada una de las consultas me da error. Adjunto la consulta y los resultados:

```sql
SELECT
    participantes.Nombre_Participante,
    sum(puntaje.Puntos) AS TOTAL,
    club.Nombre_Club AS Club,
    modalidad.Tipo_Modalidad AS Modalidad,
    categoria.Nombre_Categoria AS Categoria
FROM
    participantes ,
    puntaje ,
    modalidad_tirador,
    club ,
    distancia,
    modalidad,
    categoria
WHERE
    puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador
    AND modalidad_tirador.ID_Participante = participantes.ID_Participante
    AND puntaje.ID_Distancia = distancia.ID_Distancia
    AND puntaje.ID_Competencia = 1
    AND puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador
    AND club.ID_Club = participantes.ID_Club
    AND modalidad.ID_Modalidad = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad
    AND modalidad.Tipo_Modalidad LIKE '%Rifle 22%'
    AND modalidad_tirador.ID_Categoria = categoria.ID_Categoria
    AND categoria.Nombre_Categoria LIKE 'A'
    -- left join Total on modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador 
GROUP BY
    participantes.ID_Participante
    -- order by TOTAL desc
    -- limit 3
UNION
    SELECT
    participantes.Nombre_Participante,
    sum(puntaje.Puntos) AS TOTAL,
    club.Nombre_Club AS Club,
    modalidad.Tipo_Modalidad AS Modalidad,
    categoria.Nombre_Categoria AS Categoria
FROM
    participantes ,
    puntaje ,
    modalidad_tirador,
    club ,
    distancia,
    modalidad,
    categoria
WHERE
    puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador
    AND modalidad_tirador.ID_Participante = participantes.ID_Participante
    AND puntaje.ID_Distancia = distancia.ID_Distancia
    AND puntaje.ID_Competencia = 1
    AND puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador
    AND club.ID_Club = participantes.ID_Club
    AND modalidad.ID_Modalidad = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad
    AND modalidad.Tipo_Modalidad LIKE '%Rifle 22%'
    AND modalidad_tirador.ID_Categoria = categoria.ID_Categoria
    AND categoria.Nombre_Categoria LIKE 'AA'
    -- left join Total on modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador 
GROUP BY
    participantes.ID_Participante
    -- order by TOTAL desc
    -- limit 3
UNION 
    SELECT
    participantes.Nombre_Participante,
    sum(puntaje.Puntos) AS TOTAL,
    club.Nombre_Club AS Club,
    modalidad.Tipo_Modalidad AS Modalidad,
    categoria.Nombre_Categoria AS Categoria
FROM
    participantes ,
    puntaje ,
    modalidad_tirador,
    club ,
    distancia,
    modalidad,
    categoria
WHERE
    puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador
    AND modalidad_tirador.ID_Participante = participantes.ID_Participante
    AND puntaje.ID_Distancia = distancia.ID_Distancia
    AND puntaje.ID_Competencia = 1
    AND puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador
    AND club.ID_Club = participantes.ID_Club
    AND modalidad.ID_Modalidad = modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad
    AND modalidad.Tipo_Modalidad LIKE '%Rifle 22%'
    AND modalidad_tirador.ID_Categoria = categoria.ID_Categoria
    AND categoria.Nombre_Categoria LIKE 'AAA'
    -- left join Total on modalidad_tirador.ID_Modalidad_Tirador = puntaje.ID_Modalidad_Tirador 
GROUP BY
    participantes.ID_Participante
    -- order by TOTAL desc;
    -- limit 9;
```

Están comentadas las cosas de donde surge el error.

Este es el resultados, yo busco que imprima los 3 valores mas altos de categoría A en orden, y así con las otras dos.

```
Nombre_Participante   |TOTAL|Club                 |Modalidad|Categoria|
----------------------+-----+---------------------+---------+---------+
Carlos Valverde       |   16|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |A        |
Daniel Cazares        |   11|Paquime              |Rifle 22 |A        |
Jesus Daniel Castillo |   20|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |A        |
Anana Gastelum        |    9|Cuauhtemoc           |Rifle 22 |A        |
Joel Ortega           |   23|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |A        |
Esau Dajlala          |   20|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |A        |
Eddie Fernandez       |   10|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |A        |
Javier Garcia         |   16|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |A        |
Cosme Flores          |   17|Sierra Azul          |Rifle 22 |A        |
Manuel Payan          |   17|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |A        |
Renata Garcia         |   30|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |A        |
Fernando Ferrero      |    6|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |A        |
Luis Raul Dominguez   |   17|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |A        |
Jose Molinar          |   15|Sierra Azul          |Rifle 22 |A        |
Eduardo Garcia        |   22|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |A        |
Juan Hernandez        |   12|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |A        |
Sergio Valdez         |   10|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |A        |
Victor Bartolo        |   24|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Alejandro Chavez      |   21|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Enrique Garcia        |   11|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Homero Barraza        |   23|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Oswaldo Garcia        |   13|Sierra Azul          |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Tony Muñoz            |   17|Paquime              |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Ricardo Castillo      |   14|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Roberto Garcia Grajeda|   12|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Daniel Castillo       |   24|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Jesus Padilla         |   12|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Luis Abraham Cano     |   22|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |AA       |
Luis Carlos Oleño     |   21|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Alejandro Vazquez     |   21|Cuauhtemoc           |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Cetorado              |    9|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Oscar Yapor           |   18|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |AA       |
Martino Barsse        |   19|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Ricardo Dajlala       |   26|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Ruben Mayagoita JR    |   26|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Mauricio Rey          |   26|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Jorge Gomez           |   18|Cuauhtemoc           |Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Jesus Mainez          |   24|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Beto Garcia JR        |   23|El ganso             |Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Jesus Ruiz            |   18|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Jorge Villaseñor      |   27|30-60                |Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Luisa Mainez          |   31|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Ruben Mayagoita       |   24|30-60                |Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Luis Castañon         |   21|Cazadores y tiradores|Rifle 22 |AAA      |
Jorge Giron           |   24|Industrial           |Rifle 22 |AAA      |
```

Comment: Tan sólo encierra entre paréntesis cada SELECT con su LIMIT: `(SELECT ... LIMIT 3) UNION (SELECT ... LIMIT 3) UNION (SELECT ... LIMIT 9);`

Comment: haga la unión primero y luego lo ordena

Comment: Supongo que es mysql no? porque el group by, no esta bien. Sacando eso, esto se hace mucho mas simple con funciones de ventana (OVER)... y para colmo, esta en la documentacion un ejemplo muy similar a lo que necesitas... [mira aca](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html)